# Is there a variable for the connected wlan?

Tags: variables, cmd, wifi

I started writing this small batch file, where I get all the wlan data with:

```
netsh wlan show profile (name) key=clear
```

This is not a problem but I am asking if there is a variable like for example:

```
%CurrentWlan%
```

so I can do:

```
netsh wlan show profile %CurrentWlan% key=clear >wlan.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```bat
@echo off

for /f "eol=B tokens=*" %%A IN ('netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr SSID') do (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%A IN ("%%A") do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%%A") do (
            netsh wlan show profiles "%%A" key=clear >wlan.txt
        )
    )
)
```

Which I am going to break it down:

- We first parse the output of the command `netsh wlan show interfaces` searching for `SSID` string. As there is also a line containing `B`**`SSID`** we ignore it with `eol=B`.

  - Now, we want to parse the value **after** `:` symbol, so we set it as delimeter. We can access the network name, now, setting `tokens` to `2`.

    - We remove all unneded spaces in the result with another `for` loop specifying `tokens` option to `*`.

      - So, now, we want all the info about currently connected network (`%%A`). We redirect output to `wlan.txt`.